# How to read a password protected Excel worksheet with OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have set a password on my excel sheet. To unlock the worksheet, I modified my OLEDB connection string, but it didn't work. I got an error that "the source contains no dataRows", which means that it couldn't read the data from the excel file.

Before it was fine. What might be my problem?

This is my code:

```
public DataTable getExcelData(string fileName, string sheetName, ComboBox[] User_ComboBox)
{
    this.m_comboBox = User_ComboBox;

  // connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
   connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Password=xyz;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";

    string errorMessage = "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        // errorCode = ErrorDefinition.ERROR_OLEDBERROR;
        errorMessage = exp.Message;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `OleDbConnection` you might consider using an Excel reading library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to read the excel file. [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) supports reading password protected excel files.

You would need to implement some code to build the actual `DataTable`, but that should be simple enough. Just google it if you need to.

Comment: Thanks Rune .Since I need to use same function  in web I need to use OleDbConnection. So, Is it not possible to read password protected Excel sheet using OleDbConnection  ?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that.